# Toggle visibility script will leave two divs visible

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I have this JS code that creates a popup box and makes everything else grey in the background.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <div id="wrapper">
          <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-   box1');">Open popup box 1</a></p>
  </div>
     <div id="popup-box1" class="popupposition">
          <div id="popupwrapper">
              <div id="popupcontainer">
              ****POPUP BOX CONTENT
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

EVERYTHING ON THE BACKGROUND of the page becomes grey and not clickable, BUT this HTML part of the page remains visible, what should I do?

```
<div class="classfinder">
<div class="searchbox">
<ul>
<div class="searchboxclasswidth" onClick="return !!(classFunction() & changeColor1())"><li><p id="findclass"><a href><b>Trova classe </b></a></p></li>    </div>
<div class="searchboxcoursewidth" onClick="return !!(courseFunction() & changeColor2())"><li><p><a href><b>Trova corso</b></a></p></li></div>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you could start by showing the rest of the html. how are we to know how those two html lines relate to the rest of your document or the node you're toggling display on?

Comment: Hi @MarcB I edited, now there's a little more info

Comment: try implementing a working fiddle to show whats happening

Comment: why should they get hidden? they're not inside the div you're hiding, so they're completely unaffected by the visibility setting of that div. css settings don't work "upwards" or "sideways". they only trickle downwards.

Comment: @MarcB but everything else gets hidden, why doesn't that part get hidden?

Comment: BTW by hidden I mean they just become kind of greysh and clicking them won't have any effect

Comment: @Snowmate: It probably gets grayed out due to css of your `#popup-box1`.

Comment: @Snowmate do you have a JS fiddle or something where you can reproduce this?  Everything seems to work as you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/wy4nL9xj/

Comment: @Snowmate if everything else is getting greyed out except for that HTML bit you posted, its probably because of some CSS you have.  Please share a working example with enough code to reproduce the problem in a js fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear with the organization of HTML Controls in your page. The structure seems to be wrong. 
CSS Property z-index of parent div of pop up must be more than that of all other elements in the page to achieve the functionality that you are expecting. Compare the z-index of popup-box1 with other element that are visible above popup box.
If it doesn work out, then kindly copy paste the html as well as its associated css & JS codes here again.

Comment: CSS property of popup box are:

    .popupposition{ display: none; position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:100%; height:100%;  }

Comment: CSS of the two divs not being hidden are:

.searchboxclasswidth {
width:500px;
}
.searchboxcoursewidth {
width:500px;
margin-left:10px;
}
.searchboxclasswidth li {
  position:relative;
  background-color:#064034;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:1px;
  display: inline;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'arial';
  border-top:2px solid grey;
  border-left:2px solid grey;
  border-right:2px solid grey;
}

Comment: .searchboxcoursewidth li {
  position:relative;
  background-color:#064034;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-left:-8px;
  width:400em;
  display: inline;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'arial';
  border-top:2px solid grey;
  border-left:2px solid grey;
  border-right:2px solid grey;  
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added to the JS:

else
          e.style.display = 'block';
          e.style.zIndex="1";

And now my div is on top of everything. Thank you folks

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can also fix this issue by adding z-index:1 to popupposition class as below:

```css
.popupposition{display:none;position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:100%; height:100%;z-index:1}
```

This will avoid 1 unnecessary line of code in JS function.